# Ski lift with capacity equals N.

Tags: java, multithreading

I am learning about multithreading. It's my first task. I wrote this code and i can't move on. Task:

Ski lift with capacity equal N. 
Clients have a weight (random Ki value) and They are threads that execute in
loop:

1. downhill(sleep(big random value)
2. Try to get into the lift (if the total weight of customers is
   Less than or equal to N).
3. If it failed - they are waiting (sleep(small random value)
   and re-execute the previous point.
4. if it was successful - they go up.

   ```
   public class Client extends Thread
    {
       private SkiLift lift;
       private int weight;
   ```

   ```
   public Client(SkiLift l, int w)
   {
       this.lift = l;
       this.weight=w;
   }

   public int getWeight()
   {
       return weight;
   }

   public void run()
   {
       for (int i =0; i<10; i++)
       {
           lift.downhill(this);
           lift.goIn(this);
           this.setPriority(MAX_PRIORITY);
           lift.drive(this);
           lift.goOut(this);
           this.setPriority(5);
       }
   }
   ```

   }
   public class SkiLift 
   {
       private static int actualLoad=0;
       private static final int CAPACITY=300;

   `synchronized public void goIn(Client client)
   {
       try
       {
           System.out.println("Client " + client.getId() + " try to get into the lift");
           while (actualLoad>CAPACITY)
           {
               System.out.println("The Lift is full!");
               client.sleep((long) (Math.random()*1000));
               wait();
           }
       }
       catch (InterruptedException e) {}

       System.out.println("Client " + client.getId() + "get into the lift " );

       actualLoad+=client.getWeight();
       System.out.println("actual load = " + actualLoad);

   }

   synchronized public void goOut (Client client)
   {
       System.out.println("Client "+ client.getId() + " leave the lift  ");
       actualLoad-=client.getWeight();
       System.out.println("Actual load = " + actualLoad);
       notifyAll();
   }

   public void downhill(Client client)
   {
       System.out.println("Client nr: " + client.getId()+ " downhill ");
       try
       {   
           client.sleep((long) (Math.random()*10000));
       }
       catch (InterruptedException e){}

   }

   public void drive(Client client)
   {
       try
       {
           client.sleep(9000);
       }
       catch (InterruptedException e){e.printStackTrace();}
   }`

   }

I have three problems and i can't solve them:

1. The first who will enter must to be the first who has attempted to enter. (Just like in a queue)
2. The client who first came on the lift must also be the first to go down.
3. What is the moniotor in my program?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this question belongs to [Codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Your Client should have a state like "topOfTheMountainReached", "liftStationReached", "liftEntered", ...

Your Client then waits for this events to happen. That's also the answer to your question which element to monitor - the state, or the client itself.

For the queue you can use a `ArrayListBlockingQueue`. 
Your SkiLift then has to wait for new Clients to arrive and put them into the lift. As soon the client enters the lift, the client also gets notified that it has entered the lift. The Lift also notifies the client when the top is reached.

Here is an example of how such solution could look like. 
It uses the Java Executor Service to schedule the events for getting the client out of the lift and for reaching the lift station at the end oft the downhill part. This may also be solved differently.

The Client:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Client implements Runnable{

    final ScheduledExecutorService dhexceutors = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(500);

    final static Random DHRANDOM = new Random();

    final long weight;

    public enum State {
        goDownhill,
        waitForLift,
        goUp,
        onTop,
    }

    private State state;

    public SkiLift lift; 

    public Client(long weight,SkiLift lift) {
        this.lift = lift;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.state = State.onTop;
        goDownHill();
    }

    private void enterLift() {
        lift.add(this);
    }


    private void goDownHill() {
        synchronized (this) {
            state = State.goDownhill;
            this.notify();
        }
        dhexceutors.schedule(() -> {
            liftStationReached();
        }, DHRANDOM.nextInt(500), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); 
    }

    public void liftStationReached() {
        synchronized(this) {
            state = State.waitForLift;
            this.notify();
        }
    }


    public void topReached() {
        synchronized(this) {
            state = State.onTop;
            this.notify();
        }
    }

    public void liftEntered() {
        synchronized(this) {
            state = State.goUp;
            this.notify();
        }
    }


    public void run() {
        synchronized(this) {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    this.wait();

                    switch (state) {
                    case waitForLift:
                        enterLift();
                        break;
                    case goUp: 
                        // just wait for the topReached event
                        break;
                    case goDownhill:
                        // just wait for reaching the lift.
                        break;
                    case onTop: 
                        goDownHill();
                        break;
                    }

                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The Lift:

```
package skilift;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class SkiLift implements Runnable{

    private ScheduledExecutorService getOutClientExecutor;

    public SkiLift() {
        getOutClientExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(50);
        waitingClientsQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1000);
        occupiedSeats = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private final ArrayList<Client> occupiedSeats; 

    private long usedCapacity;

    private final ArrayBlockingQueue<Client> waitingClientsQueue;

    private final long capacity = 500;

    public void add(Client client) {
        synchronized(waitingClientsQueue) {
            waitingClientsQueue.add(client);
            waitingClientsQueue.notify();
        }

    }


    private synchronized void occupySeat(Client client) {
        occupiedSeats.add(client);
        usedCapacity += client.weight;
    }

    private synchronized void getClientOut(Client client) {
        occupiedSeats.remove(client);
        usedCapacity -= client.weight;

        // notify the waitingClientQueue that the capacity has changed
        synchronized (waitingClientsQueue) {
            waitingClientsQueue.notify();
        }

        client.topReached();
    }


    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized(waitingClientsQueue) {
                try {

                    if (!waitingClientsQueue.isEmpty()) {
                        Client c = waitingClientsQueue.peek();
                        if (usedCapacity + c.weight <= capacity) {
                            occupySeat(waitingClientsQueue.poll());
                            getOutClientExecutor.schedule(() -> {
                                getClientOut(c);
                            }, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                        } else {
                            waitingClientsQueue.wait();
                        }
                    } else {
                        waitingClientsQueue.wait();
                    }

                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the bottleneck in your system is the lift. You can only have N concurrent users of the lift.

Also, 3. mentions a Monitor. After some reading what a monitor is, you should figure out that it allows exclusive access to the limited resource, the lift.

So design your lift access to try to acquire one of the N monitors, wait a while, and at the end do not forget to release the monitor, so someone else can get it.